# loading file contents from Azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to load a las file from azure blob storage using python but I could only find ways to download it to a file path. I would like to just load the content of the file and do some processing. Is there a way to just load instead of downloading the file to a location??
The possible way would be memory stream or getting content as bytes, but I couldn't figure out a way to read the content in that case.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Is this answer what you want?https://stackoverflow.com/a/59321703/10383250

Comment: #George yes thankyou !!